# Z value rounded by ArcGIS while executing "Add XY coordinates"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ascii, xyz

I have a large vectorda (point) dataset in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 File Geodatabase that consists of 1,2 billion points that I created, converting it from ASCII file by "ASCII 3D to Feature Class tool". Now I'm trying to add X, Y and Z coordinates to the point dataset with the tool "Add XY Coordinates", but the problem is that all Z values in the end are being rounded to integers (I mean, the data field is double, but none of the Z values have decimal symbols) even though the source ASCII data stores Z values with 3 decimal symbols.

As with smaller data samples I've never encountered such a problem, can the problem be the sheer number of points (that actually takes 13 hours to process in both performed conversions)?

There's not much options to do it wrong- in the screenshot below are the options I used in "ASCII 3D to Feature Class" conversion and the "Add XY Coordinates" tool has no options in the main window at all.[image]

Comment: Perhaps z in the 1st line looks like integer

Comment: Well, Z in the first line of ASCII looks like "0.000".

Comment: I'd replace it with 0.001.